# Autosequence a value

Tags: qgis

I am using QGIS 2.18 and I have approximately 7000 road records,give or take, which require 850 of the records to be renumbered and I can not have duplicates values in the OIRID field. I need to start the record value inn the OIRID field at 6593 and sequence each record by 1 to the end to ensure I do not have any duplicates I am not having any luck with this task.  I need help accomplishing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to use QGIS 3.0 and the "add autoincremental field" tool from the processing toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

In QGIS 2.18 and assuming your "OIRID" field is sorted already, cases are:

1. "OIRID" starts from `1`
2. "OIRID" starts from `0`

(1) If "OIRID" starts from `1`, rownumber is equal to a variable @rownumber.
Then a new field will be given by an expression:

```
CASE WHEN @rownumber < 6593
     THEN "OIRID"
ELSE @rownumber
END
```

(2) If "OIRID" starts from `0`, rownumber is variable @rownumber minus 1.
Then,

```
CASE WHEN @rownumber < 6593
     THEN "OIRID"
ELSE @rownumber - 1
END
```

---

In case "OIRID" is not sorted, please try *MMQGIS* plugin `Sort Attributes` function (`MMQGIS | Modify | Sort`).